# Interval schedule question about choose the same length of time from each interval

Tags: c++, algorithm, intervals, schedule, greedy

I was struggle with an interval schedule question, the question description as follow:

> Description: Lanran has N friends. Every Sunday, Lanran has to play
>   with his friends. The i-th friend can play with Lanran from time a to
>   time b (a and b are included). However, Lanran has to play with each
>   of his friends for the same amount of time. Lanran wants to play with
>   his friends as long as possible. But he is very stupid. So he asks for
>   your help to calculate the maximum time he can play with each of his
>   friends.
>
> Input The first line contains one integer N. Each of the next N (N <=
>   5000) lines contains two integers a and b (1 <= a, b <= 10000), which
>   show the time interval of the i-th friend.
>
> Output Output a single integer, shows the maximum time Lanran can play
>   with each of his friends.

I think this a greedy problem, and I choose the minimal time friend, which is the already played time + possible playing time till b of friend, and play with him at i-th second. Here's the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
const int N = 5010;
int n, s[N], e[N], cnt[N], me;

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int low, int high) {
    int pivot = s[high];
    int i = (low - 1);

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
        if (s[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(&s[i], &s[j]);
            swap(&e[i], &e[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&s[i + 1], &s[high]);
    swap(&e[i + 1], &e[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int pi = partition(low, high);
        quickSort(low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(pi + 1, high);
    }
}

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d%d", &s[i], &e[i]);
        if (e[i] < s[i]) { printf("0\n"); return 0; }
        if (e[i] > me) me = e[i];
    }
    quickSort(0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= me; ++i) {
        int id = -1, mi = 0x7fffffff;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if (s[j] > i || i > e[j]) continue;
            if (cnt[j] + e[j] - i + 1 < mi) { id = j; mi = cnt[j] + e[j] - i + 1; }
        }
        ++cnt[id];
    }
    int ans = 0x7fffffff;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) if (cnt[i] < ans) ans = cnt[i];
    printf("%d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

So does I make something wrong? I got 7 wrong answer in 10 test cases.

Comment: There is no need to write your own swap function when there is already [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).  Also, why are you not using [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: Also please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is same as standard activity selection problem. I am pasting related standard algorithm. you can find wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem.
Greedy-Iterative-Activity-Selector(A, s, f):

```
Sort A by finish times stored in f

S = {A[1]} 
k = 1

n = A.length

for i = 2 to n:
   if s[i] ≥ f[k]: 
       S = S U {A[i]}
       k = i

return S
```